# Applying Ito's product rule to $X = tW$ and $Y = e^{W(t)}$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I am given $X = tW$ and $Y = e^{W}$ and am asked to compute $d(\frac{X}{Y})$. To me, this seems to be an application of Ito's product rule which I know to be:

$$d(X_1 X_2) = X_2 dX_1 + X_1dX_2 + G_1 G_2 dt$$ where $dX_1 = F_1dt + G_1dW$ and $dX_2 = F_2dt + G_2dW$

So following this, I write $$d(tW \cdot e^{-W}) = tW \cdot d(e^{-W}) + e^{-W}d(tW) +G_1G_2 dt$$

However, I am confused about computing $d(e^{-W})$ and $d(tW)$. The examples in my book give my a function $u(X,t)$, assume $X(\cdot) = W(\cdot) \implies dX = dW \implies F\equiv 0, G\equiv 1$, and apply Ito's chain rule:$$du(X,t) = (u_t + u_x F + \frac{1}{2}u_{xx}G^2)dt + u_x G dW$$ from $dX = Fdt + GdW$

Is $d(e^{-W}) = \frac{de^{-W}}{dt} + \frac{de^{-W}}{dW} = 0dt + -e^{-W}dW$? Or do we use the above chain rule somehow?

Comment: $$d(x_ty_t)=y_tdx_t+x_tdy_t+dx_tdy_t$$

Comment: @Khosrotash Ah, yes thank you. I've updated my post with the correction of the Ito product rule statement. My issue is with identifying $d(X_1)$, $d(X_2)$, and $G_1.G_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two facts we can use are, first we have the product rule given by $$d(f(t)G_t) = f(t)dG_t + G_tdf(t) + df(t)dG_t.$$ In this case of the rule $f(t)$ is a deterministic function. Second from Ito's formula we know if $F_t = f(W_t)$ we have $$dF_t = \frac{1}{2}f''(W_t)dt + f'(W_t)dW_t.$$

Now given $X_t = tW_t$ and $Y_t = exp(W_t)$. We want to find $dX_t$ and $dY_t$.

Using the product rule for $X_t$ we have
$$dX_t = W_tdt + tdW_t + dtdW_t = W_tdt + tdW_t.$$

Then using the fact from Ito's formula we have
$$dY_t = exp(W_t)dW_t + \frac{1}{2}exp(W_t)dt.$$

Comment: The product rule you write is written differently than what I have in my book: https://i.imgur.com/m5qVMPN.png + https://i.imgur.com/FfeSmYr.png Is $df(t)dG_t$ equivalent to $G_1G_2 dt$ ?

Comment: Given in the book is for two stochastic processes of that form. In the case of $X_t$ we have a deterministic function $f(t) = t$ and the process $G_t = W_t$, so in this case $df(t)dG_t$ is the correct Ito correction.

Comment: To make it more clear the product rule for two processes described in your book is $d(X_1X_2) = X_1dX_2 + X_2dX_1 + dX_1dX_2$. in your book they get the $G_1G_2$ by multiplying out the $dX_1dX_2$ and use the fact that $dt^2 = dtdW = dWdt = 0$ and $dW^2 = dt$, you could check this multiplication yourself that it will result in $dX_1dX_2 = G_1G_2dt$.